# Ulam Hypothesis - Minor Error

Tags: java

I'm having a minor problem with a program I'm working on. Everything works out perfectly, except for one tiny part.

```
public class Prog230b
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) // 
        { 
            int num = i; 
            System.out.print("\n" + num + ":"); 
            while(num != 1)
            { 
                if(num % 2 == 0) 
                    num /= 2; 
                else 
                    num = 3 * num + 1; 
                    System.out.print(EasyFormat.format(num,4,0)); 
            } 
        }
  }
}
```

EasyFormat is just a reference to an exterior formatting file. Below is my output.

```
1:
2:   1
3:  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
4:   2   1
5:  16   8   4   2   1
6:   3  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
7:  22  11  34  17  52  26  13  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
8:   4   2   1
9:  28  14   7  22  11  34  17  52  26  13  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
10:   5  16   8   4   2   1
11:  34  17  52  26  13  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
12:   6   3  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
13:  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
14:   7  22  11  34  17  52  26  13  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
15:  46  23  70  35 106  53 160  80  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
16:   8   4   2   1
17:  52  26  13  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
18:   9  28  14   7  22  11  34  17  52  26  13  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
19:  58  29  88  44  22  11  34  17  52  26  13  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
20:  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
21:  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
22:  11  34  17  52  26  13  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
23:  70  35 106  53 160  80  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
24:  12   6   3  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
25:  76  38  19  58  29  88  44  22  11  34  17  52  26  13  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1
```

The problem is that it prints nothing for 1. I know this is because I have while(num != 1), but I am unsure what to put instead that does not result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Can't you have a separate thing outside the `while` loop for the number one?

Comment: what is the objective/purpose of your program? what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a do-while loop instead. That way your code will execute at least one time when num starts as 1.

```
        do
        { 
            if(num % 2 == 0) 
                num /= 2; 
            else 
                num = 3 * num + 1; 
                System.out.print(EasyFormat.format(num,4,0)); 

        } while (num != 1);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you, friend.